# Page containing Microsoft Chart Control returns Service Unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mschart, servercontrols

I have a frustrating problem with an asp.net mvc view containing the Microsoft Chart control. When I request the view containing the control I get the following error.

> Service Unavailable
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is
>   unavailable.

When I run the project under the visual studio 2008 dev server it works fine. When I deploy the project to the staging server I get the error. To make this even more frustrating when I deploy to a different site on the same server under a virtual directory it works.

I also get no error messages in the event log or elmah when this happens. Has anyone else encountered this? What did you do to resolve it?

Comment: You mean the first staging deploy is _not_ under a virtual dir?

Comment: @henk-holterman Correct.

Comment: you expect an ASP.NET application to work without virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: @darin-dimitrov Yes, its deployed as a site on the server and everything else works fine except for the view with the Chart control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this was an issue with the Chart control itself. When I created a plain html view to load on the Report control I got the same error.

I believe this was some kind of conflict with one of the other HttpHandler components. I am using ELMAH and the Telerik MVC Controls. When I renamed the Controller/Routes from ReportController to ReportingController everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure the Chart http handlers/modules are defined in the web.config and that the charting dlls are in the bin on the staging site?